# How to get values for an android application

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing an android application based on web services. How can I run query (server using php and MySQL) based on the item clicked and get the result from the web. I also want to show some values as list (List layout). Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is developing a rest api that provides data for your android app. E.g. you website has some content that you want use in your app, then you could write a php script that just returns that data in a specific format.

E.g. mysite.net/rest/fetchAllLocations.php?maybe_some_parameters

This would return locations in e.g. json format, here is an example how that looks like:

[{"id":1,"shop_lng":8.5317153930664,"shop_lat":52.024803161621,"shop_zipcode":33602,"shop_city":"Bielefeld","shop_street":"Arndtstra\u00dfe","shop_snumber":3,"shop_name":"M\u00fcller","shop_desc":"Kaufhaus"}]

Here is an example for a rest api request:

http://shoqproject.supervisionbielefeld.de/public/gateway/gateway/get-shops-by-city/city/Bielefeld

So when you have your rest api set up you can deal with receiving that data with your android phone. I use a static method to get this data:

```
public class JsonGrabber{

public static JSONArray receiveData(){  
    String url = "your url";
    String result = "";

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse res = null;

    try {
        res = client.execute(method);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        InputStream is = res.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"));
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         String line = null;
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 sb.append(line + "\n");
         }
         is.close();
         result = sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    JSONArray jArray = null;

    try{
         jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
}
```

Well thats all, once you have your data in json format you just have to parse it:

JSONArray test = (JSONArray) JsonGrabber.receiveData()

```
try { 
    for(int i=0;i<test.length();i++){
    JSONObject json_data = test.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = json_data.getInt("id");
    }
}
```

The web request should run in another thread, because it can be a time consuming process. So you need to deal with AsyncTask. Here are some resources:

[Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html)
[Multithreading for performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)
[Hello Android Tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)

Comment: Thanks ArtWorkAD. Let me try this. Do you know how to parse XML using SAX in android. I have tried some link but couldn't find any better solution. I want to get some category names from a XML file and list it in the android phone.

Comment: well you could ask that in another question